# Conversion issue with nested Fragments: android.support.v4.app.Fragment VS android.app.Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-appcompat

I'm with a cross-API problem. My scenario is as follow:

1. I'm developing an application that uses **support-v4-AppCompat**, using **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**;
2. I'm using **getChildFragmentManager** to retrieve nested **Fragments**. This is a need because I have a **PageView** to scroll along several **Fragments**, one of them using **com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment** as nested Fragment;
3. I also have a need to use [ShinobiCharts](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/android/shinobicharts) as our solution is being developed with it. **ChartFragment** is a subclass of **android.app.Fragment**.

Problem comes when I try to use a nested fragment like this:

```
<fragment
    class="com.shinobicontrols.charts.ChartFragment"
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And retrieve reference to it from another Fragment like this:

```
public class TCPSpeedFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fragMan = getChildFragmentManager();
        // BELLOW LINE GIVES ERROR OF TYPE CONVERSION
        android.app.Fragment frag = fragMan.findFragmentById(R.id.chart);

}
```

As we can see, the given error is a **Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.Fragment to android.app.Fragment**. But when trying to convert them it becomes a really pain, that I haven't found solution yet.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this compatibility/conversion issue?

Comment: Their documentation states they do have a  SupportChartFragment.

Comment: I gonna check it right now!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't believe that you can get a reference to a nested `Fragment` that is defined in XML. That in itself is wrong: nested `Fragment`s can only be added & removed programmatically, and I'm surprised that you have not thought of this as a potential issue. The way you have defined that `Fragment` in XML and then tried to get a reference to it by calling `findViewById()` is incorrect.

Now coming to your main question, there is, unfortunately, **NO** way to cast `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `android.app.Fragment`. You have the following options:

- see if the library has a `Fragment` that can be used with the v4 support library
- if the library is open-source, try to modify it so that it uses `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`
- if it is not open source, you can either stop using the library and try to find another that does, or you can drop support for `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in your project and instead make use of `android.app.Fragment` everywhere in your app.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Hi ZygoteInit, thanks for your reply. I have a working code that nests two fragments in a XML inflated in the parent fragment. A com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment nested within a android.support.v4.app.Fragment, accessing it with ((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_qualitymap_map)).getMap();. I'm hopping that I can use some similar code like this...

Comment: This is news to me. I have always read that nested fragments can only be used programmatically ... but if you have really been able to do this, more power to you :)

Comment: More power for us all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I think that I have found a solution for me, in the way that I was looking for. I'm using the following lines:

```
Fragment frag = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.chart);
SupportChartFragment supportFrag = (SupportChartFragment)frag;
ShinobiChart shinobiChart = supportFrag.getShinobiChart();
```

With this, I can now compile my project with no errors.

Comment: Regarding your ChartFragmet check this out: http://www.shinobicontrols.com/forum/shinobicontrols/2014/5/shniobichart-in-fragmentstatepageradapter -> "currently our ChartFragment does not support being nested inside another Fragment.". I'm also using ShinobiCharts but as I see it your answer should not work reliable as the Shinobi documentation recommends to use the ChartView instead.